# Near Mainnet Archivel Node Set up

Tags: nearprotocol

I tried setting up the NEAR mainnet archival node using docker by following this documentation - https://github.com/near/nearup#building-the-docker-image. The docker run command does not specify any port in the document.

So I also ran the docker run without any port, but when I tried to check the port by docker ps it does not show any port but the neard node runs.

- I did not find any docs on the node APIs, can we use the archival APIs - https://docs.near.org/docs/api/rpc to query the node.

Docker run command used to set up archival mainnet node:

`sudo docker run -d -v $PWD:/root/.near --name nearup nearprotocol/nearup run mainnet`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON RPC on nearcore is explosed on port `3030`

As for the running an archival node you might be interested in this doc page https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/integrator/exchange-integration#steps-to-start-archive-node

P. S. nearup is considered oldish though still in use.

Answer (score 4):

I have updated the documentation for nearup to specify the port binding for RPC now: https://github.com/near/nearup#building-the-docker-image

You can use the following command:

```
docker run -v $HOME/.near:/root/.near -p 3030:3030 --name nearup nearprotocol/nearup run mainnet
```

And you can validate nearup is running and the RPC /status endpoint is available by running:

```
docker exec nearup nearup logs
```

and

```
curl 0.0.0.0:3030/status
```

Also please make sure that you have changed the ~/.near/mainnet/config.json to contain the variable:

```
{
...
"archive": true,
...
}
```

Comment: Sandi Thanks for the help . Node set up done.Result of status query(Removed few things from result)

{"version":"1.18.3","build":"5fd1a8bc"},"chain_id":"mainnet","protocol_version":29,"latest_protocol_version":44,"rpc_addr":"0.0.0.0:3030","validators":[{},{},{},{}],"sync_info":{"latest_block_hash":"","latest_block_height":9820210,"latest_state_root":"","latest_block_time":"2020-07-21T16:55:51.591948Z","syncing":true},"validator_account_id":null}




Can you please point me to some documentation for the Apis which i can query against the node.

Comment: Sandi i am able to query the node by using apis but i am only able to query block -9820210 as shown above in the logs.

I tried to check the logs of the container sudo docker exec nearup nearup logs 

Apr 29 05:39:24.038  INFO stats: # 9820210 Downloading headers 0.76% (25996959)  15/11/40 peers ⬇ 1.1MiB/s ⬆ 921.8kiB/s 0.00 bps 0 gas/s CPU: 43%, Mem: 1.9 GiB
Apr 29 05:39:24.038  INFO telemetry: Telemetry data could not be sent due to: Timeout while waiting for response

-Getting multiple logs like above , but my data folder size is increasing. not sure if there is a issue. Any help

Comment: The archival node will first need to download all the blocks and headers, this could take time. I would advise you to use a backup and download data from there. LInk to backup documenation: https://docs.near.org/docs/roles/integrator/exchange-integration#running-an-archival-node